# Selecting rows and updating user's info at the same time

Tags: javascript, mysql

I know this can be done easily with javascript/php, but I'm wondering if this is possible with pure MYSQL and one query.

So imagine this:
some rows are inserted with a number, that user has typed in. (for example,**5,7,1 and 2**)

So the row would now look like this:
[image: table1]

I have one more table which contains user's data:

[image]

Now: **is it possible to increase user's points by 10 if the number he had placed is above 5?**

Thank you for help,
Nedas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables to find the corresponding rows, and then update them.

```
UPDATE points_table AS p
JOIN numbers_table AS n ON p.user = n.user
SET p.points = p.points + 10
WHERE n.number > 5
```